# Use variable to seed identity?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The following doesn't work, any ideas?

```
DECLARE @seed int
// set @seed to some value

ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyTableId int identity (@seed, 1)
```

Result:

> Msg 102,
>   Incorrect syntax near '@seed'

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic SQL, but I'd usually argue that if you care about the *numerical* values of identity columns at all, you're using them wrong.

Comment: Yep, everything's wrong if you try to add an identity column to an existing table, still, I need to reseed afterwards ;-)

Comment: Changing the seed is a *maintenance* operation. Besides, parameters have no meaning with schema altering commands like `ALTER TABLE` - these are one-off commands, not something that runs repeatedly

Comment: Still you might want to use parameters in one-off commands, e.g., for automated scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, @seed)` which seems to work.

Comment: That's because changing the seed is a *maintenance* operation. It doesn't change the schema so it can't be done with a schema command like `ALTER TABLE`